# how to define the root of caffe to digits?

Tags: caffe, nvidia-digits

I have installed caffe on ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7, cuda 8,  and have tested mnist on that. it worked fine.

Now I want to install digits. I have installed it but when I do `./digits-devserver`, it gives me the following error:

```
@pc2user:~/digits$ ./digits-devserver
   ___ ___ ___ ___ _____ ___
  |   \_ _/ __|_ _|_   _/ __|
  | |) | | (_ || |  | | \__ \
  |___/___\___|___| |_| |___/ 5.1-dev

Did you forget to "make pycaffe"?
"/home/user/caffe-master" from CAFFE_ROOT does not point to a valid   installation of Caffe.
Use the envvar CAFFE_ROOT to indicate a valid installation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/user/digits/digits/__main__.py", line 70, in <module>
main()
  File "/home/user/digits/digits/__main__.py", line 53, in main
import digits.config
  File "digits/config/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from . import (  # noqa
  File "digits/config/caffe.py", line 226, in <module>
executable, version, flavor = load_from_envvar('CAFFE_ROOT')
  File "digits/config/caffe.py", line 37, in load_from_envvar
import_pycaffe(python_dir)
  File "digits/config/caffe.py", line 126, in import_pycaffe
import caffe
  File "/home/user/caffe-master/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/home/user/caffe-master/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: /home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/../../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/caffe-master/python/caffe/_caffe.so)
user@pc2user:~/digits$
```

Moreover, thsi is my `~/.profile`:
[image]

Please help me to find out how to define the root of caffe to digits.

Comment: Your error has to do with an incompatible version of `libstdc++.so.6`. You probably built with one environment and are trying to run with another. This is almost certainly caused because you're using miniconda and don't understand how it works. I suggest following the official DIGITS docs to build from source without using conda.

Comment: @LukeYeager could you link to the official docs for installing on MacOSX because I'm not seeing any? Been searching for hours without luck on exact installation advice.

Comment: We don't support MacOS officially. I think this is pretty clear in the docs.